# Utf8Value error C2661: No overloaded function takes 2 arguments

Tags: node.js, electron, v8, node-gyp

I created a node module, with a native code. I use `v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value`, and in the [documentation](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-13.2/d4/d1b/classv8_1_1_string_1_1_utf8_value.html) it's writen it needs two parameters.

So I use

```
Isolate * isolate = info.GetIsolate();
Local<Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();
Local<Array> array = Local<Array>::Cast(info[0]);
MaybeLocal<Value> maybeIndex = array->Get(context, 0);
Local<Value> index = maybeIndex.ToLocalChecked();

// This is the important line
String::Utf8Value path(isolate, index);
```

When I'm developing the module, no problem, `npm install` build it, travis as well.

But when I want to use this module in an application (electron), when I run `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd` to build my module, it fails and displays `error C2661: No overloaded function takes 2 arguments` for `v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value`.

I don't know what I miss, so it would be really great if someone know what happened to me.

You can see the code on Github, and particulary the last commit [here](https://github.com/Smiley32/windows-file-clipboard/commits/master)

Infos:
 - The module is Windows only
 - I used Node 12, and tried to upgrade it to 13, no change
 - node-gyp is version 5.0.5 when building my module, version 6.0.1 when building through `electron-rebuild`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the Electron version you're trying to build for? Ancient V8 versions didn't have the two-argument version of `Utf8Value`, but ever since the 6.2 branch (summer 2017) it has existed. So if your Electron-based app is very old, then that would explain it and updating it should fix it.

Comment: Well that was pretty dumb. I created this project not long ago, so I assumed that I have a recent electron version, but I guess not. Thanks a lot